# asp - permission error on fs.copyfolder on shared network location

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I'm a bit new to asp, so forgive me if it's a simple error.

We used to have this all working fine on our SBS2011 (sql, iis, asp site -all one location), reading and writing to shared local drive.

We've just upgraded off sbs2011 to multiple servers  (1x DC & file, 1x exchange, 1x IIS & SQL etc.). now the asp isnt working.

```
sPath="\\SERVER1\SHARED_Folder\" 

    sPath=sPath & jobnum 
    if fs.FolderExists(sPath & " " & jname) then
     response.write("Folder already exists!")
    else
    sPath=sPath & " " & jname
    fs.CopyFolder "\\SERVER1\SHARED_Folder\200\new project template", "\\SERVER1\SHARED_Folder\new project template"
    fs.MoveFolder "\\SERVER1\SHARED_Folder\new project template", sPath
```

Server1 is the file server.
if i change server1 to the iis/asp site server , it works!

ive checked permissions on the share and in the security.
IIS IUSRS, Everyone, Domain Users, Domain Admin, Users - All have Full permissions.

i have debugging - send to browser on, and all i get is:

*Server Error*

500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

With debug to server on, I get:

"Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Permission denied"

whilst the fs.copyfolder line is highlighted.

Im left scratching my head!

*Edit - forgot to mention this is an internal site only

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This will be a tricky one for us to solve, as a few mins of clicking around on the server would be worth hours of to & fro on here.

However, when you talk about permissions - I think you're on the right track. When you look at the permissions, don't forget that there's the advanced section that details what permissions are inherited. You may find that there is a inherited deny permission.

I've also seen the need for IUSRS and IUSR_ to be given permissions individually. Especially if the machine name has changed. The IUSR account that's used could be the old one. (because no new one was created.)

The other thing here, is that you appear to be dealing with local users from the IIS/SQL machine, wanting to exercise permissions on the DC/File machine.

Does that give you any useful food for thought?

Now, questions:

- Do the equivilant users on the two machines have the same user ID?
- Is the DC machine aware of the users from the IIS machine?